# Go to next item in ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that does some checks on all Domain Admins in a number of domains.
For each user account a number of checks are preformed. When one of them fails the script should go to the next admin in the list.

I currently have something like this (simplified):

```
Get-QADGroupMember "Domain Admins" | Select-Object SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {

    #Do something
    if(!ThisCheckIsOK)
    {
        break;
    }

    #Do something else
    if(ThisCheckIsNotOK)
    {
        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

This stops the whole script. Is there a way to go to the next element?

`$foreach.movenext()` does not work since `$foreach` is `null`.

Comment: Maybe you might get better answers on SO?

Comment: If it would have been a foreach in C++, then yes.  Now I'm using a Powershell cmdlet and it is clearly sysadmin-stuff.

Comment: I think it falls somewhere in between, but your question is generically Powershell (How to advance to the next element in a Powershell loop), even though the specifics are sys-admin related. Just given that there are ~500 Powershell questions on SF, and nearly 4k on SO there are probably some people more qualified to answer the question over there. That's my opinion anyway =)

Comment: *I'm not sure if generically is a word but it sounds good

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You may want to use the `Continue` statement to continue with the innermost loop.

Excerpt from `PowerShell` help file:

> In a script, the `continue` statement causes program flow to move immediately to the top of the innermost loop controlled by any of these statements:
>
> - `for`
> - `foreach`
> - `while`

Comment: Foreach-object is not foreach (and not a statement either), so this just works wrong.

Comment: This exits the whole `ForEach-Object` statement for me.  `Return` works (i.e. goes to the next object).

Comment: $foreach.MoveNext() can be used in place of continue

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer IMO as it is wrong. As the comment from @aucuparia correctly says, you have to `return` instead of `continue`. Not very intutitive but that's how it is.

Comment: @Devolus Not intuitive, but it makes sense when you consider that `.ForEach()` takes a script-block as an argument. An analogous situation exists in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 56):

You just have to replace the `break` with a `return` statement.

Think of the code inside the `Foreach-Object` as an anonymous function. If you have loops inside the function, just use the control keywords applying to the construction (`continue`, `break`, ...).

Comment: that will work for this specific occasion but may not work well in larger scripts with nested loops.

Comment: Just think of the code inside the foreach-object as an anonymous function. If you have loops inside the function, just use the control keywords applying to the construction (continue, break, ...)

Comment: @KevinColby He's right, it actually does work that way...as I discovered after much frustration when I was trying to "return" out of a function from a **Foreach-Object** loop.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to add something I learned for the next folks who land here while googling.

**In Powershell 5.1**, you want to use `continue` to move onto the next item in your loop.  I tested with 6 items in an array, had a `foreach` loop through, but put an if statement with:

```
foreach($i in $array){    
    write-host -fore green "hello $i"
    if($i -like "something"){
        write-host -fore red "$i is bad"
        continue
        write-host -fore red "should not see this"
    }
}
```

Of the 6 items, the 3rd one was *something*. As expected, it looped through the first 2, then the matching *something* gave me the red line where `$i` matched, I saw `something is bad` and then it went on to the next item in the array without saying `should not see this`.  I tested with `return` and it exited the loop altogether.

Comment: foreach(...) and ForEach-Object are two completely different constructs.  foreach works the way you describe.  ForEach-Object works as others have described.  OP is asking about ForEach-Object.

P.S.: Also foreach is an alias for ForEach-Object.  Yes this is confusing.

Comment: Furthermore for example, `$Var | % { If( $LastExitCode -ge 1 ) { Return; }; "something $_" }` you want to use `Return` to go to the next iteration of the object so `%` is yet another alias but using `Return` for those type of loops will make it go to the next iteration and not do something against the iterated variable e.g. `$_`.

Answer (score 1):

The continue statement should do what you have asked. Here is an example to ensure this is what you (or anyone who finds this post in a search) wants to do

```
$vals = @("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven");


foreach ($val in $vals)
{
    Write-Host "";
    Write-Host "$($val) before";
    
    if ($val -eq "three")
    {
        continue;
    }
    
    Write-Host "$($val) after";

}
```

> one before one after
>
> two before two after
>
> three before
>
> four before four after
>
> five before five after
>
> six before six after
>
> seven before seven after